# Make delay when .sendkeys from loop

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I've done that script is filling-up all visible inputfields in a loop.
But, I need to slow down between filling up an input fields. I need to slow down, because, our server side throwing an error messages, when you filling up to fast (optimistic logic)
Any ideas, how it is can be done?

My code for detecting input fields + filling them up is bellow:

```
List<WebElement> allInputFields = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("cm-edit-request-form dx-text-area textarea"));
if (allInputFields.size() != 0) {
    for (WebElement allInputFieldsElement : allInputFields) {
        if (allInputFieldsElement.isEnabled()) {
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable((allInputFieldsElement)));
            allInputFieldsElement.sendKeys("Automation text" + uuid);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whay do you want to _need to slow down_? Doesn't it defeats the purpose of _Automation_?

Comment: @DebanjanB, problem is, that we have a solution, when you filling up quite fast , server show u an error, that you are doing it fast :(

Comment: This error would be crucial and important along with the relevant HTML to solve your question. Update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send character by character to your input box with some delay like this(Assuming uuid is some string you initialized elsewhere) -

```
    if (allInputFieldsElement.isEnabled()) {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable((allInputFieldsElement)));
        String inputText = "Automation text" + uuid;
        for (int i = 0; i < inputText.length(); i++) {
          allInputFieldsElement.sendKeys(inputText.substring(i, i+1));
          Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom implementation for sendKeys for some WebElement :

```
public void sendKeys(String keysToSend,WebElement element){
        for(char c:keysToSend.toCharArray()){
            element.sendKeys(Character.toString(c));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(300);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to use

```
 Thread.sleep(1000);
```

*1000* is the number of milliseconds that the program will pause.